# Laravel Eloquent Replicate with slight adjustments

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to clone a single row in the DB and make a few adjustments. As you can see, I'm trying to adjust `order_date`, `order_time`, `order_type` and `order_count`. In addition, I would like it to be linked to the original order, hence the `original_id`.

```php
$Booking = $model->replicate()->fill([
    'original_id' => $this->bookingId,
    'order_date' => $fields->test_date,
    'order_time' => $fields->test_time,
    'order_type' => $fields->test_type,
    'order_count' => $OrderCount,
]);

$Booking->save();
```

However, this only creates a duplicate of the model and stores that in the DB. No adjustments.

I would like to have the adjustments there when the model is created in the DB, as observers are triggered when the model is created.

Comment: did you try to do `$Booking->original_id = $this->bookingId` etc. for each attribute instead the fill method?

Comment: Yup didn't work either. I'm not bound to the creation of a new model instead of replicating. Works, but not ideal.